# How do you force ngrok to forward to http and not https?

Tags: endpoint, portforwarding, ngrok

ngrok was forwarding to only https for me which was giving an ssl certificate error when other services tried to access the endpoint.

Most of the times ngrok forwards to http **and** https but for some reason my ngrok was only forwarding to https after using the command: `ngrok http 4554 --host-header=localhost:4554`

How do I force ngrok to forward to http and not https?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To forward to http you need to use the scheme flag as follows:

```
ngrok http --scheme=http 4545 --host-header=localhost:4545
```

This will specify to ngrok to forward to http and it the endpoint produced will be http not https.

Comment: You can forward both by specifying twice the scheme option like
`ngrok http --scheme=http  --scheme=https 4545 --host-header=localhost:4545`

Comment: if our code is running in PORT 443 then it  will not convert to http, So we don't need 443 port for local testing,
so try to use UnSecure Port like as 4545 , 8081 or others.  then it will work fine.

Comment: my command before trying to ignore https is: `ngrok http "file:///Users/myusername/Downloads"`. but now with this new command, how can I handle it? ignoring https and also hosting that folder

Comment: can I know why 4545

Comment: @Jovylle its whatever port your application is listening on

Answer (score 1):

To forward to http:

```
ngrok http --bind-tls false
```

To forward to https:

```
ngrok http --bind-tls true
```